# matlab fit exp2

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

I'm unsuccessfully looking for documentation of fit function using exp2 (sum of 2 exponents).
How to operate the function is clear:

```
[curve, gof] = fit(x, y,'exp2');
```

But since there are multiple ways to fit a sum of exponents I'm trying to find out what algorithm is used. Particularly what happens when I'm fitting one exponent (the raw data) with a bit of noise, how the exponents are spread. 
I've simulated several cases, and it seems that it "drops" all the weight on the second set of coefficients, but row data analysis often shows different behavior.

Does anyone have suggestions of documentation?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/curvefit/bszh0sy-1.html#bszh0sy-13

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I can see it doesn't really explain the algorithm it self. But I will take a second look